# std::enable_if fails to act when the wrong type (double) is passed to it instead of std::complex

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, sfinae, complex-numbers

I would like to have my array class copy data from `double` arrays to `std::complex<double>` (or any U to std::complex) arrays with `operator=`. For that, I used `std::enable_if`. It's, however, failing to detect that it should not be used.

The following function, I want to be called if type `T` is anything complex. So I used the condition `std::is_same<T, std::complex<typename T::value_type>`, because `std::complex` stores the type it uses in `::value_type`. Here's the definition of the function:

```
template <typename T, int S>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<T, std::complex<typename T::value_type> >::value, MyArray<T,S>& >::type
MyArray<T,S>::operator=(const typename std::enable_if<std::is_scalar<typename T::value_type>::value, MyArray<typename T::value_type>&, S >::type rhs)
```

This, however, gives the following error if I tried to copy `MyArray<double>`. So apparently it's failing to detect that `double` is not `

> error: 'double' is not a class, struct, or union type
>    MyArray::operator=(const typename std::enable_if::value, MyArray&, S >::type rhs)

What am I doing wrong here?

---

**UPDATE:**

I want to make what I want to acheive clear, because (sorry) there's so much confusion.

I need this operation to be possible:

```
MyArray<double> d;
MyArray<std::complex<double>> cd;
cd = d;
```

Comment: Can you show us all your code? Do you have any other overloads of `operator=`?

Comment: This seams overly complex.  Doesn't `template <typename T> MyArray<T> MyArray<T>::operator=(const std::complex<T>& rhs)` do what you want?

Comment: @kirbyfan64sos The whole code is really, really huge. I'm happy to add any bits you find necessary. Yes there's another `operator=`, but it's the standard `operator=` with nothing special.

Comment: @NathanOliver No, this is the other way around. I want to go from real to complex, not the other way around.

Comment: So what exactly are you trying to assign to your `MyArray`?  Sorry but I am having a hard time figuring it out.

Comment: `enable_if` works on function templates, not on non-template member functions of class templates.

Comment: @NathanOliver I want to assign U to std::complex<U>, so MyArray<std::complex<U>> = MyArray<U>.

Comment: @Angew Would you suggest a solution, no matter how much change is required?

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist I would, but max66 already did :-)

Comment: @Angew I'm currently working on his solution. It didn't work initially.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure to understand but... if you want enable your `operator=()` only when the incoming `MyArray<T>` is with `T` that is a `std::complex<U>`, why don't you simply write

```
   template <typename F>
     MyArray & operator= (MyArray<std::complex<F>> const & rhs)
      { return *this }
```

**--EDIT--**

> I want to assign `U` to `std::complex<U>`, so `MyArray<std::complex<U>> = MyArray<U>`.

So you want the exactly opposite.

I suppose you can do something like

```
#include <complex>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
struct MyArray
 {
   template <typename U>
   typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<T, std::complex<U>>::value,
         MyArray &>::type 
      operator= (MyArray<U> const & rhs)
       { return *this; }
 };

int main()
 {
   MyArray<double> d;
   MyArray<std::complex<double>> cd;
   cd = d;
 }
```

**-- EDIT 2 --**

> but there's a second template parameter that I removed in the original question, thinking that I'm simplifying the issue for readability. But it was wrong of me to do that, because partial specializations of functions are not allowed in C++. So my template is template , not template , which is very different

I don't think it's neccessary partial specialization

```
#include <complex>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T, int S>
struct MyArray
 {
   template <typename U>
   typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<T, std::complex<U>>::value,
        MyArray &>::type 
    operator= (MyArray<U, S> const & rhs)
     { return *this; }
 };

int main()
 {
   MyArray<double, 3> d;
   MyArray<std::complex<double>, 3> cd;
   cd = d;
 }
```

If the problem is in defining the `operator()` outside the body of the class, I propose the following, modified example

```
#include <complex>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T, int S>
struct MyArray
 {
   template <typename U>
   typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<T, std::complex<U>>::value,
        MyArray &>::type 
    operator= (MyArray<U, S> const & rhs);
 };

template <typename T, int S>
template <typename U>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<T, std::complex<U>>::value,
      MyArray<T, S> &>::type 
   MyArray<T, S>::operator= (MyArray<U, S> const & rhs)
      { return *this; }

int main()
 {
   MyArray<double, 3> d;
   MyArray<std::complex<double>, 3> cd;
   cd = d;
 }
```

**-- EDIT 3 --**

> Is there a way to do the same with the copy constructor? [...] It's quite tricky and seems impossible because there's no return type.

Yes, there is a way

```
#include <complex>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T, int S>
struct MyArray
 {
   template <typename U>
   typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<T, std::complex<U>>::value,
         MyArray &>::type 
      operator= (MyArray<U, S> const & rhs)
       { return *this; }

   template <typename U,
            typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<T,
                           std::complex<U>>::value>::type>
   MyArray (MyArray<U, S> const & rhs)
    { }

   MyArray() = default;
   MyArray(MyArray const &) = default;
   MyArray(MyArray &&) = default;
   ~MyArray() = default;
 };

int main()
 {
   MyArray<double, 3> d;                      // need MyArray() = default
   MyArray<double, 3> d2(d);                  // OK
   MyArray<float, 3> f;                       // OK
   MyArray<std::complex<double>, 3> cd(d);    // OK
   //MyArray<std::complex<double>, 3> cd2(f); // error!
   cd = d;

 }
```

Observe the `= default` added lines; without the first one (I don't know the other three are usefull or not) the code doesn't compile because (if I understand correctly) the SFINAE copy constructor disable (delete) the default copy constructor so delete the other default constructors and the default destructor.

Comment: See the comment thread under the Q.  This is not what the OP wants.  I had the same thought and asked.

Comment: What I need is the opposite. Please check the update.

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist - I've seen your comment; modified my answer.

Comment: This gives me the error: `error: invalid use of incomplete type 'class MyArray<_T, _S>'
 MyArray<T,S>::operator=(MyArray<U, S>& rhs)`

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist - interesting; modified the example to show the `main()` (with your example) and includes; it compile with my g++ (4.9.2) and clang++ (3.5); can you show us a minimal example that give the error?

Comment: I'm sorry, but there's a second template parameter that I removed in the original question, thinking that I'm simplifying the issue for readability. But it was wrong of me to do that, because partial specializations of functions are not allowed in C++. So my template is template <typename T, int S>, not template <typename T>, which is very different.

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist - I see... modified my answer to add a `int S` template type

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist - another example in case the problem is in the outside body class definition

Comment: Is there a way to do the same with the copy constructor? I would appreciate your help with that. It's quite tricky and seems impossible because there's no return type.

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist - added an "Edit 3"; attention: observe the "= default" added lines

Answer (score 1):

Something I find helps when trying to understand template problems is try a replacement yourself:

```
template <double>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<double, std::complex<typename double::value_type> >::value, MyArray<double>& >::type
MyArray<double>::operator=(const typename std::enable_if<std::is_scalar<typename double::value_type>::value, MyArray<typename double::value_type>& >::type rhs)
```

Is it obvious now? If `double` is your `MyArray` type `T`, then that `T` will be used in your SFINAE logic above. But `double` does not have a `::value_type`.

You might try something like this:

```
template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_scalar<T>, MyArray<T>&>::type
  MyArray<T>::operator=(const std::complex<T>& rhs){...}
```

And if you don't need the `is_scalar` check, use max66's answer instead.

**Update:**
Okey-dokey. So this *should* address wanting to go from `MyArray<T>` to `MyArray<std::complex<T>>` via the assignment operator and not the other way around.

```
template<typename T, typename U>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<T, std::complex<U>>::value && std::is_scalar<U>::value, MyArray<T>&>::type
  MyArray<T>::operator=(const MyArray<U>& rhs){...}
```

The trick here is that `int` and `std::complex<int>` are not the same type. You can also do it by substituting `T::value_type` for `U`. Finally, you can do it by partially specializing your `MyArray<T>` class for cases where it's `MyArray<std::complex<T>>` class, which, if you ever find yourself needing more things like what you were asking, might be worth considering.

Comment: What I need is the opposite. Please check the update.

Comment: Could you please consider the existence of a second `int` template parameter? I think this is the source of the problem. Please take a look at the updated code I put in my question.

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist Your updated code you put in your question shows using `double` as an example... What do you mean a second `int` template parameter?

Comment: There's a second template parameter that I removed in the original question, thinking that I'm simplifying the issue for readability. But it was wrong of me to do that, because partial specializations of functions are not allowed in C++. So my template is `template <typename T, int S>`, not `template <typename T>`, which is very different.